# Manual trigger mouseover event or simulate hover effect on point

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I have such pie chart

```
chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    backgroundColor: 'none',
    renderTo: 'pie-charts-continer'
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a3VDp/

and my biggest headache how to simulate hover effect, when we are hovering on small inner black circle. I created it only for visual effect, it should look like a shadow. Any suggestion?

Comment: Which inner black circle are you talking about?

Comment: @GurpreetSingh [About this](http://d.pr/i/kw0A) inner black circle

Comment: Maybe donut chart will be better solution http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same solution as previously - just update properties via attr() for designed slice. See: http://jsfiddle.net/a3VDp/1/

```
function mouseOver(element) {
  element.defaultR = element.graphic.r;
  element.graphic.attr({
    r: element.defaultR + 10
  });   
}
```

In chart:

```
            mouseOver: function (e) {
                var x = this.x,
                    d = this.series.linkedParent.data[x];
                mouseOver(d);
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you draw that inner circle as a svg circle element and then add a listener for hover / mouseenter event to that element?

Comment: Can you please show me example how to do it in shorter and easy way?

Comment: And, how to slice this svg circle equivalent to the chart part?